# Laravel subfolders not loading on server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, windows, web

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have granted permissions for all the subfolders

web.php

```
Route::get('/', [MainController::class, 'main']);


// Index
Route::get('/ControlPanel/index', [IndexController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/ControlPanel/index/{denied}', [IndexController::class, 'index']);
```

The index file loads but not the other files which are in subfolders.
The controllers' path is setup correctly as it works on my local system but not on the server

Local System is Windows 10 and Server is RHEL AWS - EC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-** Enable mod_rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

**2-** To activate these changes restart Apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now check your web page is it working or not. If not follow Step 3.

**3-** Edit Apache Configuration file

To Edit run below command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Then add following block of code below <VirtualHost *:80>

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Save the file and exit.

**4-** Restart apache2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled and so is AllowOverride. 
Could you please explain how only the index file works? is it my code or?

Comment: I complated the answer check it again @AkashR